# Is there a page that lists all the suggested edits which have been approved, or not?

Tags: support, tools

I know there is a page for the suggested edits approved (or not) from a user. Is there an equivalent page for the all the suggested edits, independently from the user who approved them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10k tools → "links" tab → "suggested edit stats" → "all" → "all". (Yes, that's "all" two times.)

Comment: That page doesn't report the suggested edits that have been rejected. (That is what I meant with "(or not)".)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: it appears that in the "all" tab, all the accepted edits come first, and all the rejected ones come after that (starting on page 15 right now). In the "day" tab, all edits are sorted chronologically.

Comment: I was expecting them to be sorted chronologically.

Comment: Yeah, so was I. But at least they're all there.